# how do I make a tkinter window follow with text?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a Treasure Island type game and I'm trying to make the screen follow the text e.g if the text goes off the screen the screen automatically scrolls down to fit in the text. I've tried various types of this by different people mostly scrollbars but I can't get any to work, I currently have a "scrollbar" set up but it doesn't work.

here's the code:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter as ttk

from Treasure_Island_V2_art import Treasure_Chest, Pirate_Ship

window = tkinter.Tk()

window.title("Treasure Island")
window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
window.config(bg = "black")

window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

text = tkinter.Text(window, height=10)
text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tkinter.EW)

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(window, orient='vertical', command=text.yview)
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tkinter.NS)

text['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set

logo = tkinter.Label(window, text = '''
          |                   |                  |                     |
 _________|________________.=""_;=.______________|_____________________|_______
|                   |  ,-"_,=""     `"=.|                  |
|___________________|__"=._o`"-._        `"=.______________|___________________
          |                `"=._o`"=._      _`"=._                     |
 _________|_____________________:=._o "=._."_.-="'"=.__________________|_______
|                   |    __.--" , ; `"=._o." ,-"""-._ ".   |
|___________________|_._"  ,. .` ` `` ,  `"-._"-._   ". '__|___________________
          |           |o`"=._` , "` `; .". ,  "-._"-._; ;              |
 _________|___________| ;`-.o`"=._; ." ` '`."\` . "-._ /_______________|_______
|                   | |o;    `"-.o`"=._``  '` " ,__.--o;   |
|___________________|_| ;     (#) `-.o `"=.`_.--"_o.-; ;___|___________________
____/______/______/___|o;._    "      `".o|o_.--"    ;o;____/______/______/____
/______/______/______/_"=._o--._        ; | ;        ; ;/______/______/______/_
____/______/______/______/__"=._o--._   ;o|o;     _._;o;____/______/______/____
/______/______/______/______/____"=._o._; | ;_.--"o.--"_/______/______/______/_
____/______/______/______/______/_____"=.o|o_.--""___/______/______/______/____
/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/_____ /
''')

logo.grid()
logo.config(font=('arial', 15), fg = "green", bg = "black")

line1 = tkinter.Label(window, text=("Welcome to Treasure Island,\n"
                                    "Your goal is to find the buried Treasure!"))

label1 = tkinter.StringVar()

a = tkinter.Label(textvariable=label1, font = ('arial', 20), fg = "blue", bg = "black")

a.grid()
for i in line1.cget("text"):
      a=label1.get()
      label1.set(a+i)
      window.after(50)
      window.update()

space = tkinter.Label(window, text=" \n \n ")

space.grid()
space.config(bg = "black")

line2 = tkinter.Label(window, text="You wake up to find yourself laying in the middle of a deserted beach,\n"
                                   "you feel hungry but you see something that catches your eye.")
label2 = tkinter.StringVar()

b = tkinter.Label(textvariable=label2, font = ('arial', 20), fg = "blue", bg = "black")

b.grid()
for i in line2.cget("text"):
      b=label2.get()
      label2.set(b+i)
      window.after(30)
      window.update()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your a and b labels need a height value to stop them from expanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `canvas` with a `frame` inside to contain the widgets you would like to scroll; Create a scrollbar for the `canvas` and create widgets inside `frame`.

Use `onFrameConfigure(canvas)` listen to `Frame` size change, and use `canvas.yview_moveto( 1 )` to scroll to the end of window.

Reference: [Scrollbar in Tkinter grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290958/scrollbar-in-tkinter-grid?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I also suggest to change the font for text art to [monospaced fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), e.g. consolas

```
import tkinter

from Treasure_Island_V2_art import Treasure_Chest, Pirate_Ship

def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
    canvas.yview_moveto( 1 )

window = tkinter.Tk()

window.title("Treasure Island")
window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
window.config(bg = "black")

window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

# set Canvas and Frame for scrollbar

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, border=0, highlightthickness=0, background="black")
frame = tkinter.Frame(canvas, background="black")
scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(window, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tkinter.NS)
frame.grid()
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tkinter.NSEW)
canvas.create_window((canvas.winfo_screenwidth()/2,0), window=frame, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)
frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas: onFrameConfigure(canvas))

# Create widgets inside Frame

logo = tkinter.Label(frame, justify='left', text = '''
          |                   |                  |                     |
 _________|________________.=""_;=.______________|_____________________|_______
|                   |  ,-"_,=""     `"=.|                  |
|___________________|__"=._o`"-._        `"=.______________|___________________
          |                `"=._o`"=._      _`"=._                     |
 _________|_____________________:=._o "=._."_.-="'"=.__________________|_______
|                   |    __.--" , ; `"=._o." ,-"""-._ ".   |
|___________________|_._"  ,. .` ` `` ,  `"-._"-._   ". '__|___________________
          |           |o`"=._` , "` `; .". ,  "-._"-._; ;              |
 _________|___________| ;`-.o`"=._; ." ` '`."\` . "-._ /_______________|_______
|                   | |o;    `"-.o`"=._``  '` " ,__.--o;   |
|___________________|_| ;     (#) `-.o `"=.`_.--"_o.-; ;___|___________________
____/______/______/___|o;._    "      `".o|o_.--"    ;o;____/______/______/____
/______/______/______/_"=._o--._        ; | ;        ; ;/______/______/______/_
____/______/______/______/__"=._o--._   ;o|o;     _._;o;____/______/______/____
/______/______/______/______/____"=._o._; | ;_.--"o.--"_/______/______/______/_
____/______/______/______/______/_____"=.o|o_.--""___/______/______/______/____
/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/_____ /
''')

logo.grid()
logo.config(font=('consolas', 15), fg = "green", bg = "black")


line1 = tkinter.Label(frame, text=("Welcome to Treasure Island,\n"
                                    "Your goal is to find the buried Treasure!"))

label1 = tkinter.StringVar()

a = tkinter.Label(frame, textvariable=label1, font = ('arial', 20), fg = "blue", bg = "black")

a.grid()
for i in line1.cget("text"):
      a=label1.get()
      label1.set(a+i)
      window.after(50)
      window.update()

space = tkinter.Label(frame, text=" \n \n ")

space.grid()
space.config(bg = "black")

line2 = tkinter.Label(frame, text="You wake up to find yourself laying in the middle of a deserted beach,\n"
                                   "you feel hungry but you see something that catches your eye.")
label2 = tkinter.StringVar()

b = tkinter.Label(frame, textvariable=label2, font = ('arial', 20), fg = "blue", bg = "black")

b.grid()
for i in line2.cget("text"):
      b=label2.get()
      label2.set(b+i)
      window.after(30)
      window.update()

window.mainloop()
```